# Converting HTML tables to bootstrap columns - Responsive Design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on an old product that we have, that currently uses HTML tables to display its content. In this world of responsiveness, I would like to make that responsive. After reading up online, I believe it might end up being a lot of work to rework the whole website, however, I am trying to find a solution that would convert any table into columns based on divs that contain bootstrap columns. A very example of this is given here for a login page:[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eshsrvcq/2/)

I don't have access to the source of the fields, however, I can add elements (append/prepend) using jQuery. I can also add CSS styles.

Could someone help me out in this approach, please?

```
<table></table>
.
.
.
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Cheers.

Comment: If it's tabular data, keep it as tables. If they've used tables for layout, then this is a great approach, but using jQuery to change the DOM in this fashion is probably not the best idea. Is there any way to gain access to the source?

Comment: Its not really tabular data, its just creating forms using tables. I don't really have access to the source because its an application development system and fields are defined on a server level. However, I do have access to the front-end and I can manipulate fields and DOM.

Comment: Have you checked this ? http://divtable.com/generator/

Comment: @VincentG: That just does the convert for you when you click on that button, isn't it. How can I make it work on my webpage on the fly?

Comment: I think, if you can't have access to HTML structure, you can do a fix using CSS, like this fiddle for example : http://jsfiddle.net/shigemimatsumoto/Ww8hq/

Comment: I don't see any CSS there and its just like a normal table, no responsiveness.

Comment: Hey. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but I've used this in the past to make tables responsive https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php. If you want me to code out and example for you below let me know. I've had it go to a list style view from 760px and below and it's worked well.

Comment: If you have access to bootstrap just lookup how they used the following class: `table-responsive`. If you can add classes to the html, great. If not look up how bootstrap solved this kind of problem with their class and just add your own css code to the whole table tags.

Comment: @Megajin `table-responsive` does not answer the question, nor does it actually make the table responsive. It is possible to convert the tables into a responsive design.

Comment: See my updated answer below, with a solution based upon your jsFiddle.

Comment: @JackBrown let me know if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be hard to flawlessly convert any given table to bootstrap columns. Consider that bootstrap columns only allow for up to 12 columns and a table may have more than that.

This function will convert a table to BS rows/cols, but it assumes the number of table rows is evenly divisible by 12 (if not, you'll have to adjust it to your own needs).

```
/**
 * Convert a table to bootstrap columns
 * @param table DOMElement
 */
function makeBSCols(table){
    var html = ["<div class='container'>"];
    $(table).find('tr').each(function(){
        var $td = $(this).find('td').length ? $(this).find('td') : $(this).find('th');
        // get the column width
        if($td.length > 12) return alert("too many columns");
        var cls = Math.floor(12/$td.length);
        if(cls!==(12/$td.length)) return alert("invalid column count");
        html.push("<div class='row'>");
        $td.each(function(){
            html.push('<div class="col-sm-'+cls+'">'+$(this).html()+'</div>');
        });
        html.push('</div>');
    });
    html.push('</div>');
    $(table).replaceWith(html.join(''));
}
```

Example: `makeBSCols(document.getElementById('myTable'))` ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6j38L8w1/))

For a more flexible solution, (assuming you're actually displaying tabular data) you might consider just using BS tables rather than BS cols/rows. This one will just add BS styles to your table and put it in a `.table-responsive` div which helps with responsiveness.

```
/**
 * Convert a regular table to bootstrap table
 * @param table DOMElement
 */
function makeBSTable(otable){
    var table = $(otable).clone(); console.log(table);
    table.addClass("table-hover table-bordered table-striped table");
    var div = $('<div class="table-responsive" />');
    $(otable).replaceWith(div);
    div.append(table);
}
```

Example: `makeBSTable(document.getElementById('myTable'))` ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q48my1ha/))

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for your answer. Could you provide your answer based on my JsFiddle please?

Comment: @JackBrown I updated your fiddle. See my answer elsewhere in this thread.

Answer (score 2):

> **To the OP:** You need to rewrite your tables in entire project

As per your requirement you don't want to rework any of the tables that are built and Also you want to convert existing tables to responsive div's.

Firstly to give a solution that can work on your entire project it is very important that **all the tables in your site follow same standard in its struture**. Which I see from the login page its very random at the moment.

Even if you write a solution that can work on the screen you provided (login screen) I am not sure if that will be sufficient for your entire site. Tables in your screen are nested to the core. You never know what all might break if you take this aproach.

So **my suggestion is**.. What was done is done.. Previous developers used to use only tables to structure there pages, But the world has changed to responsiveness. And it will change in the next few years too. We never know. So its high time for you to **rewrite all the pages into new HTML structure and be upgraded to latest possible code**.

---

> **To general public:** who want to change table to divs according to devices

**Quick Check:** [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/rvthogbw/) (resize the result screen to see the effect)

As far as I understand the requirement you want to show a `table` in medium and large devices, But when the user is on small device or resize the screen to small then you want to display it in different manner, More like a `div` structure.

I have a solution using inbuilt bootstrap classes.

**Solution:**

- Create both your table (that you show in medium and large devices) and the other HTML structure (that you want to show in small devices).
- Use bootstrap provided **[Helper Classe](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)** to toggle the display of table and the other section according to the viewport.

  Here is the snap from the Doc's and a [TestCase](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#visible-on)

[image]

So with the above given details all you need is ..

```
// the tables are visible only on medium and large devices
<table class="visible-md-block visible-lg-block"> 
  //..your table structure
</table>

 // This section is only visible in small and extra small devices
 <div class="visible-xs-block visible-sm-block"> 
  //The table data represented in a div structure.
  //Each row can be structured as sections with header as label and row data as value.
 </div>
```

**Disadvantages:**

- With this approach you will end up with additional HTML if user is in any device Or never resizes the screen.

**Advantages:**

- This doesn't require you to keep tack of when the screen is resized so that you build the new section. Which also means you dont need Jquery.
- This doesnt reuire you to find out which device is the user on.
- Working is slick as its only CSS

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the "nicest" form to solve your problem, but if you can only use CSS and jQuery I think you can just div every part of the table data, use `$(...).hide()` to make it invisible and then use `$(...).html()` to place that content into the Bootstrap's div's.

Answer (score 1):

i think you would have to rewrite your whole html if the site is based on html tables.

If you use tables just as "normal" tables you could just add `class="table` to your table

furthermore you could wrap your table inside an div with `class="table-responsive"`

e.g.:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

there also some further styles available: `table-hover` `table-striped` ...
you can find some samples here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right that a complete refactor might cost a lot of work. However I would really consider a more let's call it hybrid solution: Why not pick some components and refactor them nicely. The old product you have will improve significantly, but just not 100% in the first step. For the parts which cannot be refactored right now, make a nifty plan. The solutions mentioned by others address your question perfectly, but I think you'll be stuck with a unmaintainable product in the end. And nobody will benefit from such a product, right?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is divided columns and rows that are responsive to all device try this

use this type of responsive design.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offser-2 col-lg-5">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to pull information and simply add it to the table you have. I use the tags  then the headers as  and inside it I use normal  and  tags. Works for me. I use jQuery to pull data and add to the table. It's quite easy to do.

Something useful for responsive bootstrap pages could be using the table code below and placing it in a  where you create a column such as:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"> /*You can place the table in here*/ </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the sample table code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>header 1</th>
          <th>header 2 </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        /*You could pull and add the data in here with <tr> and <td> using                   jQuery*/
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
It was not clear from the original post that the author needed to deal with deeply nested tables. I have [updated his JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eshsrvcq/1/) accordingly.

Here's some jQuery code I wrote a while back which converts tables into bootstrap rows and columns on the fly. It assumes that the table is symmetrical, no colspan or rowspan attributes.

One of the primary concerns when converting a table to a bootstrap layout is to handle the header row properly. This jQuery code will do that provided that all of the header cells are using the th tag. You could easily just assume anything on the first row was a header by replacing `find('th')` with `find('th,td')`.

Lastly, it is important to preserve the attributes of the original table, such as id's, classes and onclick events. Any events that were added programmatically may need to be reapplied.

```
$('table:not(:has(table))').each(function() {
    debugger;
    var rowSelector = 'tr';
    var attributes = $.map(this.attributes,function(a,i) {
       return a.name+'="'+a.value+'"';
    }).join(' ');

    // handle collapsible headers
    var $headers = $('tr:first', this).find('th');
    var columns = $('tr:first',this).find('th,td').length;
    if ($headers.length > 0) {
        $headers.closest('tr').addClass('row visible-sm visible-md visible-lg');
        $headers.addClass('form-group  col-sm-' + Math.floor(12 / $headers.length)).wrapInner('<label></label>');
        rowSelector = 'tr:not(:first)';
    }
    // add classes to each data row
    $(rowSelector, this).addClass('row').each(function() {
        $('td,th', this)
            .addClass('form-group col-sm-' + Math.floor(12 / columns))
            .filter(function() {
               return $headers.length > 1;
            })
            .each(function (i) {
               // add collapsible headers to each row
               $(this).prepend('<label class="visible-xs">' + $($headers[i]).html() + '</label>');
            });
    });
    // convert input elements to bootstrap styled controls 
    $(':input', this).addClass('form-control').css('width', '');

    var divs = '<div class="container"><div '+attributes+'>'+$(this).html()
        .replace(/<\/{0,1}tbody>/gi, '')
        .replace(/<(tr|td|th)/gi, '<div')
        .replace(/<\/(tr|td|th)/gi, '</div')+'</div></div>';
    $(this).replaceWith(divs);
});

$('table').each(function() {
    var rewrite = $(this).html()
        .replace(/<(\/{0,1})table/gi, '<$1div')
        .replace(/<\/{0,1}tbody>/gi, '')
        .replace(/<(\/{0,1})(tr|td|th)/gi, '<$1div');
      $(this).replaceWith( rewrite );
});
```

Given this sample table

```
<table>
  <tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Address</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Zip Code</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Jake</td><td>Elwood</td><td>1060 W Addison St</td><td>Chicago</td><td>IL</td><td>60613</td></tr>
  <tr><td>John</td><td>Wayne</td><td>18601 Airport Way</td><td>Santa Ana</td><td>CA</td><td>92707</td></tr>
</table>
```

Results in the following bootstrap markup:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row visible-md visible-lg">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>First Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>Last Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>City</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>State</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>Zip Code</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label class="visible-xs visible-sm">First Name</label>
        Jake
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label class="visible-xs visible-sm">Last Name</label>
        Elwood
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label class="visible-xs visible-sm">Address</label>
        1060 W Addison St
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label class="visible-xs visible-sm">City</label>
        Chicago
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label class="visible-xs visible-sm">State</label>
        IL
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label class="visible-xs visible-sm">Zip Code</label>
        60613
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label class="visible-xs visible-sm">First Name</label>
        John
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label class="visible-xs visible-sm">Last Name</label>
        Wayne
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label class="visible-xs visible-sm">Address</label>
        18601 Airport Way
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label class="visible-xs visible-sm">City</label>
        Santa Ana
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label class="visible-xs visible-sm">State</label>
        CA
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label class="visible-xs visible-sm">Zip Code</label>
        92707
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tables are for tabular data. If that is what is in the tables, it would be best to keep them as tables. This is for semantic reasons as well as accessibility (and compliance with Section 508 in the USA). You can use the `.table-responsive` class to help make it look better on mobile and not break anything.
There are other things which make tables more responsive such as [stackable](http://johnpolacek.github.io/stacktable.js/) and [tablesaw](https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw) to name a few.
Even if you convert to bootstrap's rows and columns, you have a set 12-column grid, if they content of the table does not fix in there nicely, it will have a bad user experience.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. Tables are merely a type of container. When I first started doing web development, there weren't very many alternatives, and no such thing as css,divs, sections or articles. If you wanted multiple columns, say the left column for field labels and the right for input elements, the table was your only option.

Comment: @B2K Tables are for tabular data. If you are putting things that are not tabular data (as you suggested) then this answer does not apply to you. This compiles with [WCAG 2.0 - H51](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H51.html)

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me. Tables should be for tabular data. That isn't how they were used until recently. I was designing websites when Netscape 1.0 was released. That said, specs are all fine and good, but when dealing with legacy websites telling someone what they should have done isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tablesYouWant = document.querySelectorAll("yourSelection"); //A selection of elements
for(var i = 0; i < tablesYouWantl i++){
    i.class += "classNames"; //Add Bootstrap classes to the elements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should need to add a class like this using bootstrap class table -responsive

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```